# XML unmarshal not working on First element

Tags: xml, go

I'm trying to unmarshal XML.

```
type XMLCSFP struct {
    Version string `xml:"version,attr"`
}

type XMLCS struct {
    Container XMLCSFP `xml:"container"`
}


v2 := XMLCS{}
data := `
<container xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container" version="1.0">
    <rootfiles>
        <rootfile full-path="EPUB/package.opf" media-type="application/oebps-package+xml"/>
    </rootfiles>
</container>
`
err = xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &v)
    if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
    return
}
fmt.Println(v)
```

It's not showing me the version `1.0`. The struct value is `nil`

**But when I wrap the xml with `div` container. It's working fine.**

```
data := `
<div>
<container xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container" version="1.0">
    <rootfiles>
        <rootfile full-path="EPUB/package.opf" media-type="application/oebps-package+xml"/>
    </rootfiles>
</container>
</div>
`
```

What is the problem with the first one? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root element of XML is unmarshalled into the type of the pointer provided. In your case, this is `XMLCS`. Since `version` is an attribute of the root element, it will go into a field named `version` in `XMLCS`, if present.

So changing your struct as below should fix the problem,

```
type XMLCS struct {
    XMLName string `xml:"container"`
    Version string `xml:"version,attr"`
}
```

Read the [documentation of Marshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal) for details on how XML is mapped to structs.